# Split string by capital letters (excluding hyphenated words)

Tags: c#, string, xpath, split, watin

I am using WatiN to click links in the browser based on the string i pull off the site.

The problem is that some of the text it pulls is off of multiple lines, so it combines the string into 1 word. example: 
"Ultra Corrosion-Resistant Coated Alloy Steel"   becomes "Ultra Corrosion-ResistantCoated Alloy Steel"

I am trying to split the string by all capital letters except ones that are hyphenated, so that i can start searching for links by portions of the string.

this is what i have so far

```
              types = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3[@class='AbbrPrsnttn_PrsnttnNm']");
                foreach (HtmlNode type in types)
                {
                    desc = type.InnerText.CleanText();

                    if (browser.Div(Find.ById("ProdPrsnttnGrpCntnr")).Element(Find.ByText(desc)).Exists)
                    {
                        browser.Div(Find.ById("ProdPrsnttnGrpCntnr")).Element(Find.ByText(desc)).Click();
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                        types = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3[@class='AbbrPrsnttn_PrsnttnNm']");
                        doc2.LoadHtml(browser.Html);
                        partTable = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='ItmTblGrp']");

                        MineNext(doc, doc2, browser, typeUrl, types, desc, partTable);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        split = desc.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });

                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how it might be achieved:

**Updated** to also separate numbers.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace SplitOnUppercase
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            const string text = "Test42-10 UltraCorrosion-ResistantCoated Alloy-SteelNumberTest42";
            var result = new StringBuilder(text.Length);
            for (var i = 0; i < text.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                result.Append(text[i]);
                if (text[i] != ' ' && text[i] != '-' && (char.IsUpper(text[i + 1]) || !char.IsDigit(text[i]) && char.IsDigit(text[i + 1])))
                    result.Append(' ');
            }
            result.Append(text[text.Length - 1]);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: another question. i just realized that some of the substring has numbers in it, that i also want spaced.

for example:

"Wire-Lockable 18-8 Stainless Steel"

and

"Metric Flange-Head Class 12.9 Alloy Steel"


if i am only adding spaces between the words starting with a capital then they will have a number tagged on the end of them. 

how would i go about spacing on the first instance of a number like

12.9 or 18-8?

Comment: could you give an example, like "source string" -> "desired converted string"?

Comment: Well i realized how I need to do it. I actually do need to use Split, so that I can use the indexes to build pieces of the initial string.


I am taking strings that might start like this "Self-Locking18-8 StainlessSteel Button Head" and I want to convert them to "Self-Locking 18-8 Stainless Steel Button Head" but the problem is that when I am using WatiN to tell the browser to click the link based on that string, sometimes the full string isnt found. So i will have to make a shorter string using the split, and parse off maybe the last 2 words so I am just searching for "Self-Locking 18-8"

Comment: if it helps, this is a page for an example of what I'm working with.

http://www.mcmaster.com/#socket-head-cap-screws/=k5c4cu

if you inspect each part, you can see that most of the names ar broken up by spans, and on separate lines, which give me the problem.

Comment: @webminer07: I understood what you meant now, I'll update the answer.

Comment: that works perfectly! i then did     desc = result.ToString();

but even though the string is finally right, and i use "desc"

browser.Div(Find.ById("ProdPrsnttnGrpCntnr")).Element(Find.ByText(desc)).Click();

when it looks on the browser, it cannot find the match because they are on different lines. so can i start cycling through and taking words off the end of the string until it finds it in the browser window?

like "Left-Hand Thread Black-Oxide Alloy Steel" ---> "Left-Hand Thread Black-Oxide Alloy"

then "Left-Hand Thread Black-Oxide" then "Left-Hand Thread Black" until it succeeds?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Char.IsUpper("C")` to find the indices to split on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure String.Split(Char[]) is case sensitive, but I cant test this at the moment.
I'm not at a computer where I can test or write c#, but this should work logically. There are probably a lot of syntax errors in this.

```
Char[] splitChars = {'A', 'B', etc....}; //what the string will be split by
string desc = inputString; // input string
string[] splitByCapital = desc.Split(splitChars);
string[] output = new string[splitByCapital.length];
for (int i = 0; i < splitByCapital.length; i++)
{
    if (splitByCapital[i].Contais("-"))
    {
        output = splitByCapital[i] + splitByCapital[i-1];
    }
    else
    {
        output = splitByCapital[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here an example I put together using Linq. There are probably many ways to improve this.

```
public static string TransformLinqExample(this string toTransform)
        {
            string answer = toTransform
                .ToCharArray()
                .Select(c => new string(c, 1))
                .Aggregate((a, c) => a += (CapitalLetters.Contains(c) && c.IsUpper() && !a.EndsWith("-") && !a.EndsWith(" ")) ? " " + c : "" + c);
            return answer;
        }
```

Here's a complete example.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace SplitProblem
{
    public static class StringAndCharExtensions
    {
        const string CapitalLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        public static bool IsUpper(this string theChar)
        {
            return theChar.ToUpper() == theChar;
        }
        public static string TransformLinqExample(this string toTransform)
        {
            string answer = toTransform
                .ToCharArray()
                .Select(c => new string(c, 1))
                .Aggregate((a, c) => a += (CapitalLetters.Contains(c) && c.IsUpper() && !a.EndsWith("-") && !a.EndsWith(" ")) ? " " + c : "" + c);
            return answer;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string toSplit = "Ultra12.4 34.2 Corrosion-ResistantCoated 18-6 AlloySteel";
            string tranformed = toSplit.TransformLinqExample();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\n\n", tranformed);

            foreach (var part in tranformed.Split(' '))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(part);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to make use of Regular Expression to split on capital letters (The following code won't split the string on special characters or numbers, to do so, update the regex pattern to include the special characters and numbers).

```
    var inputString = "AnyStringThatYouWantToSplitOnCap";
    var pattern = "[A-Z][a-z]+";
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
    var matches = regex.Matches(inputString);
    StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Match item in matches)
    {
        value.AppendFormat("{0} ", item.Value);
    }
```